# How to turn a text value into a multiplication result in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in an Excel sheet where the cell values look like this:

19 x 16 x 15

The cells are formatted as text.

I would like to have another column that would treat the numbers as such and the "x" as a multiplication and just show the X * Y * Z result in the cell.

I tried playing around with formatting and a formula but to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interesting, I did some looking around as well and it seems like it's near impossible without using VBA.  But the VBA solution is very simple --

You'll need to save the workbook as Macro Enabled

First get it into the right format, so if your data starts in A1, make a formula in B1:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x","*")
```

Open the VBA editor (Alt+F11), go to Insert-Module, and paste this into the code window :

```
Function Evalu(ByVal S As String) As String

    Evalu = Evaluate(S)

End Function
```

It makes use of the Evaluate function, which was apparently removed from newer versions of Excel.

Use the function in Column C with:

```
=Evalu(B1)
```

Alternatively, do it all in one column.. if your data starts in A1, then in B1 use:

```
=Evalu(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x","*"))
```

Kind of lame you cant do this without VBA, people get antsy (for good reason) opening macro enabled workbooks.  One option, use this trick to get it to evaluate all the cells, then Copy-PasteAsValue to get rid of the formulas, then save as an xlsx.

Hope this helps, maybe someone can find a non-vba method.  Found the techninique here:http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2212496,00.asp

Comment: yes, it does help a lot. Thank you for the level of details.

Answer (score 3):

With no error detection, and assuming that A1 contains a product of three numbers:

> LEFT(A1,SEARCH("x",A1)-1)*MID(A1,SEARCH("x",A1)+1,SEARCH("x",A1,SEARCH("x",A1)+1)-SEARCH("x",A1)-1)*RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("x",A1,SEARCH("x",A1)+1))

In the above, LEFT, RIGHT, and MID all return numbers as text, but since we're multiplying the results, Excel converts the text to numbers for free.
-HTH

Comment: AWESOME. Works perfectly as written.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in cell A1:

```
19 x 16 x 15
```

You can use this formula in cell B1:

```
=IFERROR(PRODUCT(INDEX(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),"x",REPT(" ",99)),99*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x",""))+1))-1)+1,99)),)),"Invalid String")
```

So that B1 processes A1 as `19*16*15` and provides the correct result of `4560`

Comment: Yes, `4560`, thank you! I was missing a +1 so it was omitting the last number for multiplication, oops >_<.  I have edited the post to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You might apply Text to Columns with `x` as the delimiter and, if your data starts in A1, a formula such as:

```
=A1*B1*C1
```

Answer (score -1):

If you must format them as text, assuming your cells are $A$1, $B$1, and $C$1,I would do something like:

```
=VALUE(LEFT($A$1,FIND(" x ",$A$1)-1))*VALUE(MID($A$1,FIND(" x ",$A$1)+3,(FIND(" x ",$A$1,FIND(" x ",$A$1)+1)-2)-(FIND(" x ",$A$1)+2)))*VALUE(RIGHT($A$1,LEN($A$1)-FIND(" x ",$A$1,FIND(" x ",$A$1)+1)-2))
```

Comment: Since the strings extracted by the text functions are strings, there is a need for VALUE because they will be treated as text otherwise.

Comment: No. It works fine with mathematical operators.  Try inputting it into a formula requires a numerical value, however, like:

    =SUM(LEFT(A1,1)*RIGHT(A1,1))